# Descobrir de qual tabela o dado é, em um union

Tags: sql

Olá,
Tenho um sistema php, usando o codeigniter, e nele roda o seguinte comando:

```
$data['dados_tabelas'] = Tabela1::find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM tabela1) UNION (Select * from tabela2)');
```

Mais ou menos isso. 
Eu queria saber se tem como eu descobrir quais dados vieram de qual tabela, pois quero trazer pra view os dados da tabela1 de uma cor e os da tabela2 de outra cor.
Obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um identificador no select e depois fazer um if no seu codigo

```
$data['dados_tabelas'] = Tabela1::find_by_sql("SELECT 'tbl1' as identificador,* FROM tabela1) UNION (Select 'tbl2' as identificador,* from tabela2)");
```

Answer (score 2):

pelo que eu saiba não dá mas você pode trazer o nome da tabela dentro do resultado de cada linha, algo assim:

```
SELECT
    id,
    batata,
    outro_campo,
    'tabela1'
FROM
    tabela1
UNION
SELECT
    id,
    pao_de,
    nome,
    'tabela2'
FROM
    tabela2
```